# Is there any fast way to draw gradients with color given by a 2D function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, simulation

So I'm creating a small program for physics simulations in Python. Basically it simulates the evolution of some fields and points based on some differential equations. I made some simple visualisation of what is happening using pygame, and it worked well (it's just drawing circles, so nothing special). But then I wanted to also render field values. I tried using a pygame surface with color values determined by a field value at that point, but it's just too slow, even after changing the code so that I don't iterate over anything and instead do all operations on numpy arrays.

So my question is: can this be done faster in pygame, and if not, what other graphical library would be best for that purpose?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. practically: do you have some examples of the source data, an example of the resulting plot, and how you know it's too slow (ie. how long did it take)?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create gradient image use **Pillow** module:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


height, width = 800, 500 # the height and the width of the image
image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), '#FFFFFF')

a, b, c = 0, 113, 189   # first color in rgb format
x, y, z = 181, 217, 231 # second color in rgb format
for i in range(height):
    a, b, c = a + (x - a) / 500., b + (y - b) / 500., c + (z - c) / 500.
    ImageDraw.Draw(image).line((0, i, width, i), fill=(int(a), int(b), int(c)))

image.save('image.png', 'PNG')
```

[image]